# Round Corner Window in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying window corner rounded in wpf but still Grid corner showing .

### **Looks like this type of issue:**

https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fdontpaniclabs.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2014%2F12%2Ftransparent_WPF1.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fdontpaniclabs.com%2Fblog%2Fpost%2F2014%2F10%2F30%2Frounded-corners-with-transparent-backgrounds-in-wpf%2F&tbnid=TD_RmzKgFCi6LM&vet=12ahUKEwjeqNKH_ZL0AhU4KLcAHXkaDwAQMygBegUIARCwAQ..i&docid=Q-nsUFZ1FM7sAM&w=550&h=367&q=round%20window%20corners%20wpf&ved=2ahUKEwjeqNKH_ZL0AhU4KLcAHXkaDwAQMygBegUIARCwAQ

---

**I am using this style.**

Comment: You forgot your style... but set WindowStyle="none" and AllowTransparancy="True" in the window and it should work.

Comment: And the funny thing, if you click on the picture your linked, you would get the answer...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should make you window borderless (with `WindowStyle="None"`) and transparent (with `AllowsTransparency="True"` and `Background="Transparent"`). Then add `Border` control and set `CornerRadius` property with desired value and `Background` property with desired color. As you can't put all Window content into `Border` control, you should add another sub-Grid for all Window elements and put sub-Grid and Border into main `Grid`.

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WPFApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="400" 
        Height="200"
        WindowStyle="None"
        Background="Transparent"
        AllowsTransparency="True">
    <Grid>
        <Border CornerRadius="25" 
                Background="White" />
        <Grid x:Name="Content" 
              Margin="10">

            <!-- Put all window content here -->

            <Label Content="CONTENT HERE" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                   HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
                   VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                   FontSize="24"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, It's Working...